# Google Gam Powershell export report to csv

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and I am looking to write a script to export gam reports to csv files.

```
$list = Import-Csv "\\Qdata.rcsd.internal\F$\Exports\Google\Student Accounts\studentaccounts.csv"
foreach ($entry in $list)
{
    C:\Tools\gam-RCSDKIDS\gam.exe create user $($entry.newuser) firstname $($entry.firstname) lastname $($entry.lastname) password $($entry.password)
}
```

I am using the above command to import from a csv and it works great.

I want to know download gam reports to a csv file

```
\\zdata.rccc.internal\F$\Import\Google\Student Accounts\allgoogle.csv
```

I am looking to to use gam print users allfields

```
\\zdata.rccc.internal\F$\Import\Google\Student Accounts\allgoogle.csv
```

I played around with this but have not had any luck.  I know there is an `export-csv` command but not sure how to apply it.

Comment: Hello, I read this wiki about CSV, maybe you learn what you need. https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/BulkOperations#using-csv-files